# socat tunnel via ssh to socket with colon character ':' in it's name. How to escape it?

Tags: bash, ssh, socat

Socket file on my remote machine has a colon ':' in it's name and unfortunately I can't do anything about it.
socat gives me an error message **E UNIX-CONNECT: wrong number of parameters (2 instead of 1)**

```
socat "UNIX-LISTEN:$SOCKET_DIR/mysqld.sock,reuseaddr,fork" \
EXEC:'ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey_rsa.pub myuser@myhost socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT\:"/path/to-socket:and-some-more-name"'
```

Clearly **:** is the problem `"/path/to-socket:and-some-more-name"`

Unfortunately I cannot find any reasonable way to escape it.

Comment: Can you create a symlink to the socket (with a cleaner name), and use that?

Comment: It worked in my case. ~thanks